# Can we find the antiderivative of the following expression using these identities only

Tags: integration

$$\tan^3(x)\sec(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Using substitution and the identities:
$\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, $\sin^2(x) = \cfrac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$, $\cos^2(x) = \cfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$, the expressions for tan and cos. Also, we can only directly integrate expressions of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.

Comment: That's not a very good question. In fact, it's not really a question at all. Considering that you've asked reasonable questions before, surely you know by now that this is not up to the site's standards.

Comment: It's possibly even worse now.

Comment: can someone just do it? It's not an unclear question

Comment: It's still not a **question**.

Comment: is it a question now?

Comment: Now it's a question, but it's still bad (giving no personal input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bioche's rules* say we can get it with the substitution $u=\cos x$. Indeed
\begin{align*}
\int\tan^3x\sec x\,\mathrm d\mkern1mux&=\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\cos^4x}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mux=\int\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^4x}\,\sin x\,\mathrm d\mkern1mux\\
&=\int\frac{u^2-1}{u^4}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu  u=\int\frac1{u^2}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu  u-\int\frac1{u^4}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu u\\
&=-\frac1u+\frac1{3u^3}=-\frac1{\cos x}+\frac1{3\cos^3x}+C.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

We start by using the trigonometric identity

$$\tan^2(x) = \sec^2(x) - 1$$

So we get:

$$\int \tan(x)\sec(x)\left(sec^2(x) - 1\right)\mathrm {d}x$$

Now we make the substitution $u = \sec(x)$ so $\mathrm {d}u = \tan(x)\sec(x) \mathrm {d}x$.

I'll let you try to integrate the term by term and factorize out the constant, getting:

$$\int u^2\ \mathrm {d}u - \int 1\ \mathrm {d}u$$

which is nothing but

$$\frac{u^3}{3} - u + c$$

Now we have to substituting back $u = \sec(x)$, to get the result:

$$\frac{\sec^3(x)}{3} - \sec(x)$$

or also

$$\frac{1}{3}\sec(x)\left(\sec^2(x) - 3\right)$$

Done.

Comment: @BLAZE Why on earth would you edit a perfectly fine answer to change from $dx$ to $\mathrm{d}x$, which is really just a matter of personal opinion? See for example http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17132

Comment: @mrf because it looks better you remember the argument over 'excessively large integrals' that is a matter of opinion as well

Comment: @BLAZE Says who? There are people vehemently preferring one form to the other, and it's a **personal** opinion. Feel free to use straight d:s in your own posts, but don't impose your own taste on others.